# JSON REST endpoint returning / consuming JSON literals

Tags: json, rest, service

Is it advisable or not in a RESTful web service to use JSON literal values (string / number) as input parameter in the payload or in the response body?

If I have an endpoint `PUT /mytodolist` is it OK for it to accept a JSON string literal value `"Take out the rubbish"` in the request payload (with `Content-Type=application/json`) or should it accept a JSON object instead (`{"value":"Take out the rubbish"}`)?

Similarly, is it fine for `GET /mytodolist/1` to return `"Take out the rubbish"` in the response body or should it return a proper JSON object `{"value":"Take out the rubbish"}`

Spring MVC to makes implementing and testing such endpoints easy, however clients have flagged this as non standard or hard to implement. In my point of view JSON literals *are* JSON, but not JSON objects, so I'd say it is fine. I have found no recommendations using Google.

**EDIT 1: Clafirication**

The question is entirely about the 'standard', if it allows this or not.

I understand the problem with the extensibility, but one can never design a fully extensible interface IMHO. If changes need to be done, we can try extending what we have in a backwards compatible way, but there *will* come a time when it becomes messy and an other approach is required - which is commonly handled by versioning the API in one way or another. I find it a fair point even though, because using literals as request/response body *immediately* becomes inextensible, while coming up with a reasonable one-attribute JSON object does not.

It is also understood that some frameworks have problems with handling JSON literals, this is the origin of this question. The tool I used happened to support this, so I thought this was all right, but the front-end library did not.

Still, what I am intending to find out right now, is if using JSON literals is according to the de-facto standard (even if it is a cornercase) or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use JSON object always. One reason is that for Content-Type application/json people expect something staring with "{" and not all frameworks will handle json literals properly. Second reason is that probably you will add some additional attributes to you list item (due date, category, priority, etc). And then you'll break backward compatibility, by adding new field.

Comment: After reading Clarification I still recommend to return JSON because it is more common way.

Answer (score 0):

It may be acceptable in the context of your example, but keep in mind that unambiguous interfaces are easier to use and that will encourage adoption.

For example, your interface could interpret `"Take out he rubbish"` as the same as `{task:"take out the rubbish"}`, but once you add additional properties (eg `"when"` or `"who"`) the meaning of a solitary string in the request becomes ambiguous. It's inevitable that you'll add support for new properties as your interface matures.